# MongoDb aggregation framework to group elements of inner array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB aggregation framework trying to transform each document:

```
{
  "all": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "type": "A",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "type": "A",
      "id": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

into this:

```
{
  "unique_type_A": [ "3", "1" ]
}
```

(final result is a collection of n documents with unique_type_A field)

The calculation consists of returning in an array all the uniques types of entities of type A.

I got stuck with `$group` step, anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply this logic to each document, you can use the following;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$all"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "all.type": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "type": "$all.type",
        "oldId": "$_id"
      },
      unique_type_A: {
        $addToSet: "$all.id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Where we first [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), to be able to filter and play with each member of `all` array. Then we just filter the `non type:"A"` members. The [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage has the difference with a complex `_id`, where we utilize the `_id` of `$unwind` result, which refers back to the original document, so that we can group the results per original document. Collecting the `id` from `all` array with [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) to keep only unique values, and voilà!

And here is the result per document;

```
[
  {
    "unique_type_A": [
      "3",
      "1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "unique_type_A": [
      "4",
      "11",
      "5"
    ]
  }
]
```

Check the code interactively on [Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0WyoANTf8Vi)

Comment: I edited the question because I think I was not clear enough. I'm not expecting a single final aggregation, but to transform each document (final result is n documents). BTW that online tool is just great.

Comment: @italktothewind updated the answer =) yeah I know it is pretty great online tool!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I though that maybe we can use something to apply grouping inside the document (without splitting it and grouping it again)

Comment: @italktothewind there are always alternatives, but it will become an hard-to-maintain code, I prefer the readable pipeline unless there is a performance issue etc.

Comment: In fact there is a performance issue, I'm applying this to 100 million documents haha

Comment: @italktothewind can you check the performance of this right now? Not good enough? You can add a filter at the beginning to filter out all without an `"A"` in their `all` array, but mongo might be already doing that in its optimized pipeline.

Comment: My pipeline is not finished yet (I'm trying to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331815/co-ocurrence-count-using-mongo-aggregation-framework), but I can come later and tell you!

Comment: @italktothewind you can do something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RjVzncpatJ9) ?

Comment: I prefer the latest solution, you should add it to the answer! Thank you!!